# How to Set up Facebook conversion API in woocommerce with cURL

Tags: wordpress, api, facebook, woocommerce

How can I set up this conversion API in wordpress woocommerce website. I need to send data though this cURLs once an order is made.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/using-the-api

```
curl -X POST \
  -F 'data=[
       {
         "event_name": "Purchase",
         "event_time": 1626842391,
         "user_data": {
           "em": [
             "309a0a5c3e211326ae75ca18196d301a9bdbd1a882a4d2569511033da23f0abd"
           ],
           "ph": [
             "254aa248acb47dd654ca3ea53f48c2c26d641d23d7e2e93a1ec56258df7674c4",
             "6f4fcb9deaeadc8f9746ae76d97ce1239e98b404efe5da3ee0b7149740f89ad6"
           ],
           "client_ip_address": "123.123.123.123",
           "client_user_agent": "$CLIENT_USER_AGENT",
           "fbc": "fb.1.1554763741205.AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz1234567890",
           "fbp": "fb.1.1558571054389.1098115397"
         },
         "contents": [
           {
             "id": "product123",
             "quantity": 1,
             "delivery_category": "home_delivery"
           }
         ],
         "custom_data": {
           "currency": "usd",
           "value": 123.45
         },
         "event_source_url": "http://jaspers-market.com/product/123",
         "action_source": "website"
       }
     ]' \
  -F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/<PIXEL_ID>/events
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this way. Please, Anyone can conform it ? I need to move forward how to do the rest implementation. And wanted to know how we can get that fbc and fbp value from the user for assign to this json.

```
$data = array( // main object
    
    
    "data" => array( // data array
        
        array(
            "event_name" => "Purchase",
            "event_time" => time(),
               "user_data" => array(
                "client_ip_address" => $ip,
                "client_user_agent" => $browser,
                "em" => $email,
                "ph" => $phone,
                "fbc" =>'',
                "fbp" =>''
                ),
                "contents" => array(
                "id" => $item_ids,
                "quantity" => count($item_qty),
                "delivery_category"=> "home_delivery"
                ),
                "custom_data" => array(
                "currency" => "GBP",
                "value"    => $order_total,
                ),
                "action_source" => "website",
                "event_source_url"  => $fullURL,
       ),
    ),
       "access_token" => "{Access Token}"

    );  
    
    
    $dataString = json_encode($data);                                                                                                              
    $ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{PIxel ID}/events');                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($dataString))                                                                       
    );                                                                                                                                                                       
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```